# create firebase user with google login .getCurrentUser() returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

simple question: I want to use the credencial obtained from

```
        GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

and

```
private GoogleSignInAccount konto;
 private void handleSigninResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
    if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()) {
        konto = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
    }
```

later on I tried to play a little bit with firebaseAuth:
in the oncreate method:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "firebase user " + firebaseUser.getUid() + "    -   " + firebaseUser.getEmail());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No firebase user ");
            }
        }
    };
```

and later in the onStart method I called this method:

```
 private void firebasewithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acc) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebasewithGoogle  " + acc.getId());

    AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acc.getIdToken(), null);

    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential)

            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override

                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


                    } else {

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.

                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                        //Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }


                }

            });
}
```

the "onComplete" method is never called, because there is no user in the firebase user authentication database.

How is the user created when using a googleSignin User?
For email and PW a

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()
```

is used. is there a way to do the same with the ".getIdToken()" retrieved for the google provider?
or:

```
AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acc.getIdToken(), null);
```

thanks for any hints.

**EDIT 1**

I set up an exact class like in the example : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android for the GoogleSignInActivity.java Everything is working fine except the user auth for firebase fails.
So I guess something is wrong with the firebase console setup.

- google provider is enabled
- email password is not needed so disabled
- web client ID (from the console) is passed to .requestIdToken("") for the GoogleSignInOptions

Anyone knows what could be wrong?

**EDIT 2**
the task:

```
.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
```

throws:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project XXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. ]
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users says You create a new user in your Firebase project by calling the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method or by signing in a user for the first time using a federated identity provider, such as Google Sign-In or Facebook Login.                                                                                                                  But my users are not created

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my tutorials step by step, the entire authentication process using **[Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5)** and **[Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRt9Ts0fRU&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=6)**.

Comment: Thx for the comment I'll have a look on it.

Comment: I watched the really nice tutorial, however you didn't include the authentication setup in the firebase console? I think you left the database open for read and write for all users?

Comment: Yes, I skiped the easiest part, how to add Firebase to your project. Also the version of dependencies are changing constantly. By the way, I always recommend you use the latest versions. Yes, it was only for testing purposes.

Comment: The easiest part is funny, that could be the part which gives me troubles ;-)

Comment: You could think about giving a tutorial about authentication and user creation.

Comment: There are many tutorials out there. The best way to learn Firebase is the docs. The user creatin is present in that tutorial.

Comment: Yes indeed, actually this is not the problem. I need to troubleshoot the above mentioned issue.

Comment: Have you done what the error said?

Comment: Yes it leads you to create a JSON file. But not the Google json

Comment: So, which one ?

Comment: It is generated in the API section of your Google account. Just replace the xxxx in my cuestion with your project number.

Answer (score 2):

So, With the aid of the firebase support I sorted it out:

the Identity [Toolkit API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com) was enabled **AFTER** I downloaded the 
google-services.json config file.

It's very important that you verify you're using the latest google-services.json config file in your app. Go to "Project Settings" in your Firebase Console and re-download it. Place it on your app folder inside your app's directory and re-compile your app.